# WebUSB and U3 enabled flash drives

Tags: webusb

I'm curious if the WebUSB API is capable of working with a U3 enabled flash drive.

The U3 flashdrives have a hidden, read-only partition that contains a small ISO file that acts as a physical CD ROM drive when inserted into a Windows computer and was able to use the autorun function in XP machines to execute on insertion.

The U3 enabled flash drives could be made to pull up a web browser (Firefox, Opera etc) or other executables that were embedded inside the U3 enabled flash drive.

It is theorized that the STUXNET worm used to infiltrate Irans nuclear plants was executed by a U3 enabled flash drive.

U3 technology was ended after Microsoft changed how Windows handled autoplay on Vista and higher due to widespread abuse.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U3_(software)

Answer (score 0):

WebUSB cannot be used to connect to USB mass storage drives (either emulating a disk drive or CD-ROM drive).